# Почему Input не видит файл?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Отправляю на сервер файл (`<input name = "image"/>`), он нормально доходит и есть в массиве `$_FILES`, но `Input::file('image')` выдает пустой массив. Почему это может происходить?

P.S.: Притом, функция `Input::hasFile('image')` возвращает `true`.

Comment: На форме есть этот атрибут ? `enctype="multipart/form-data"`